# php while loop update the same value in single table description

Tags: php, mysql

I am generating the report from MySQL database using php programming for Leave Management project.

```
// mysql query to fetch the report

SELECT * FROM vrv_intranet_leaverequest 
                   WHERE 
                   ((fromdate >='2014-03-10' and fromdate <='2014-03-20')
                   || 
                   (todate >='2014-03-10' and todate <='2014-03-20'))
```

i am getting 10 line items from this query

```
Id Name   01/03  02/03 03/04 04/04 05/05 
25 Suresh   L     P      P     P   P     
25 Suresh   P     L      P     P   P
28 Balaji   L     L      P     P   P
29 Kumar    P     P      L     L   P
30 Sri      P     L      P     P   P
31 Ganesh   L     L      P     P   P
45 Alex     P     P      P     L   L
```

Am getting the 25th ID is two time in table because on my database i have records. But i want to show on front in single row.

The 25th id is leave on 1st and 2nd so its showing like two records. But i want that in single record look like below:

```
Id Name   01/03  02/03 03/04 04/04 05/05 
25 Suresh   L     L      P     P   P
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP BY` to collect all the rows with the same ID, and `MIN()` to select the minimum value in each column:

```
SELECT Id, Name, 
        MIN(`01/03`) AS `01/03`, 
        MIN(`02/03`) AS `02/03`,
        MIN(`03/04`) AS `03/04`, 
        MIN(`04/04`) AS `04/04`, 
        MIN(`05/05`) AS `05/05`
FROM vrv_intranet_leaverequest
WHERE ((fromdate >='2014-03-10' and fromdate <='2014-03-20')
        || 
       (todate >='2014-03-10' and todate <='2014-03-20'))
GROUP BY Id
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that Id is primary key

```
SELECT * FROM vrv_intranet_leaverequest WHERE 
 ((fromdate >='2014-03-10' and fromdate <='2014-03-20') || 
 (todate >='2014-03-10' and todate <='2014-03-20')) GROUP BY Id
```

Comment: `SELECT distinct Id, *` --- 1. `DISTINCT` (in this case) is applied to the whole record, not to a field. 2. You cannot specify `*` after fields, only in the beginning